# Outlook on MacBook Pro, Imported Contacts Don't Display-Answered

Tags: mac, microsoft-outlook

I am new to Mac, just received MacBook Pro.   I have Outlook installed.  I imported my contacts to Outlook from a .pst file a couple of days ago. After I finished the import I was able to see all of the contacts under "People."

I opened Outlook today. When I press "people" only one of my contacts displays.

I can search and access the contacts.

How can I make all of the contacts display?

(I checked all categories to "display" - I checked General-Preferences, sidebar "hide on my computer folders" is unchecked.)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you see these imported contacts when login to webmail interface of your email account? You may also try to clear the folder cache to see whether it helps: right-click your contacts folder > Properties > Empty Cache.

Comment: Thanks for this tip.   Turning on the folders (View--Sidebar) helped identify/clean up the issue.